# Get the row of each different column A with highest value for another column B

Tags: sql, sqlite

I know the title is a bit messy, but I will show the problem black in white right now.

I have a table like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id int primary key,
    item_type int,
    item_value int
);
```

The actual table is a bit different, but this is a simplified version for the sake of understanding.

Now, what I want to get in a SELECT query is those with the greatest item_value for each different item_type.

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT item_id, 
       item_type, 
       item_value 
FROM   items 
GROUP  BY item_type 
ORDER  BY item_value DESC;
```

That seems to do the trick, but it takes aeons to run, and I think it is utterly suboptimal. For that matter it would be faster to do one query for each type, but I wonder if there is a way to do the same in only one query with a join or so.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you mean by "highest value for each different `item_type`".

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Well, the data may vary. Slow is relative, indeed, what I mean is that my query is probably one of the slower ways to do that –if not the slowest–. highest value should be redacted better as "greatest item_value". I am going to edit that.

Comment: Please note that this query returns a *random* row from each group. It happens to work only by chance; this may change if the table or index structure or SQLite version changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query suggested by CL seems to take the same amount of time (measured with .time on) than mine, although for me his query looks more clear than mine.

Indexing only item_type doesn't seem to make difference for any of the two queries, what finally have worked is to create an index with the three columns like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_items_tvi ON items(item_type, item_value, item_id)
```

After that, the speed has improved A LOT (from about three seconds to just one half of a second ceteris paribus).

Comment: This is a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx); this is usually not worthwhile for every query.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL forbids this, but in SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can select a row from a group with MAX():

```
SELECT item_id,
       item_type,
       MAX(item_value) AS item_value
FROM items
GROUP BY item_type;
```

To make this query efficient, you need an index on the `item_type` column.

Comment: Thanks. By the time I read your answer, I had already created an index with the three columns in the order item_type, item_value, item_id and speed has increased dramatically. When using without indexes, your query and mine seem to take a similar amount of time. Indexing only item_type doesn't seem to make a difference, but creating an index with item_type, item_value and item_id as I did does improve the speed A LOT.